# Simple OpenID authentication code for .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid

Is there a simple example of OpenID authentication implemented using MVC ?

Comment: Darin Dimitri have answer this question beautifully [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706061/login-with-fb-connect-google-oauth-in-net/4706201#4706201)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/). You can also take a look at this blog [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) from Scott Hanselman.

Answer (score 1):

[RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) is yet another OpenID library.

[Authenticating users with RPXNow (in ASP.NET MVC)](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/07/27/Authenticating-users-with-RPXNow-%28in-ASPNET-MVC%29.aspx)

Comment: And advantage over DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: RPX is include OpenID selector.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get much simpler than this:

I just installed dotnetopenauth through nuget to a new project (forms authentication included), and then followed this tutorial which is pasting 3 small chunks of code and it worked.

http://andrewblogs.com/blog/openid-for-asp-net-mvc-a-quick-setup/

Answer (score 0):

I know a im a bit late but look here
http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleID
Now i haven't tried it but it seems like the fastest solution and its based on DotNetOpenAuth

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete step by step article how to add OpenID authentication to ASP.NET MVC 3 application. It shows how to combine OpenID with stanard FormAusthenication model, so you can use either e-mail/password or OpenID.

Complete solution code is available. It worked for me with some minor tweaking to get user's e-mail, first and last name in addition to OpenID :-)

**OpenID Authentication with ASP.NET MVC3 , DotNetOpenAuth and OpenID-Selector**

http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx